# Chartjs tooltip location when enlarged

Tags: charts, chart.js

I am using chartjs line chart in a webpage with 4 divs.  When the mouse is hovered on a div the div is enlarged using css

```
.box:hover  { 
z-index: 10000;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
-moz-transform:    scale(1.5);
-o-transform:      scale(1.5);
-ms-transform:     scale(1.5);
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
-moz-transition-duration: 1s;
-o-transition-duration: 1s;
-ms-transition-duration: 1s;
border-width: 2px;
border-color: black;
border-style: solid;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

When the div is enlarged the tooltips do not match 
[image: Week 12 is over 8]

Before I go digging into the code, can someone point me in the right direction?

I also just noticed the location of the tooltip is about where the mouse should be when the tooltip should show up.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed in current master branch and as well as 2.0 dev version. Please get latest from the GitHub Chartjs repo and check the tooltip sample files.

The issue was the tooltips getting generated used relative positioning dynamically. The code sample is updated to use proper positioning for both relative and absolute positioned elements.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with chart.js.  2.0 is coming out soon, so I will wait for that.